# WordPress - Menulinks turn into an empty link and dont know where to start

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The menu list converts to:

```
<ul class="art-hmenu menu-8">
    <li class="menu-item-"><a></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-"><a></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It does register the amount of menu items I put in, but it doesnt set the title and the right . Help would be much appreciated.

If you need more info, please dont hesitate to ask. I don't know what exact info would be relevant to solve this issue.

I have looked into different files such as functions.php and header.php, but I couldn't identify the problem. I am not familiar with PHP, so I could use some help.

EDIT:
Here is the code example that I tried (found here on Stack Overflow) but that didn't solve my problem:

```
//register menu
    function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array('main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu' ) )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

//template usage
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>

//code for adding new menu items
function new_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
        $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
        $items = $homelink . $items;
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );
```

This fix didn't change anything for me (that I could see).

EDIT 2:
Here is the code for the header that displays the menu.

```
<?php if (theme_get_option('theme_use_default_menu')) { wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary-menu') );} else { ?><nav class="art-nav">
        <div class="art-nav-inner"></div>
    <?php
    echo theme_get_menu(array(
            'source' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_source'),
            'depth' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_depth'),
            'menu' => 'primary-menu',
            'class' => 'art-hmenu'
        )
    );
    get_sidebar('nav'); 
?>
```

Together with:

```
function theme_get_menu($args = '') {
    $args = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args', $args );
    $nav_menu = apply_filters( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', null, $args );
    if ( null !== $nav_menu ) {
        return $nav_menu;
    }
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, array('source' => 'Pages', 'depth' => 0, 'menu' => null, 'class' => ''));
    $source = &$args['source'];
    $menu = &$args['menu'];
    $class = &$args['class'];
    if ($menu != null && is_string($menu)) { // theme location
        $location = theme_get_array_value(get_nav_menu_locations(), $menu);
        if ($location) {
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($location);
            if ($menu) {
                $source = 'Custom Menu';
                $class = implode(' ', array($class, 'menu-' . $menu->term_id));
            }
        }
    }

    if ($source == 'Custom Menu' && $menu != null) {
        $nav_menu = theme_get_list_menu($args);
    } elseif ($source == 'Pages') {
        $nav_menu = theme_get_list_pages(array_merge(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title'), $args));
    } elseif ($source == 'Categories') {
        $nav_menu = theme_get_list_categories(array_merge(array('title_li' => false), $args));
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu', $nav_menu, $args );
}
```

Comment: Start by figuring out what code is used to output that navigation. Sounds like it might use a custom WP_Nav_Walker implementation - one that is simply faulty somehow.

Comment: You need to share the code in the questions which you have tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.